# Android Studio: Getting JDocTest to work

Tags: java, android, doctest

Currently my team is working on some more complex code which our app will use and although we have UnitTests running we would really like to be able to use JDocTest so that we can create tests while we write some of our smaller methods.

I have successfully followed the instructions from JDocTest github read me and compiled it into my project. However I'm having trouble running the particular .java class files. I'm trying to be able to run MatrixCreator.

[Here is what my directory looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt16J.png)

[Here is my attempt to set up MatrixCreator under application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljXdP.png)

I get the error

> Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'AvocadoCoreProject'.
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar
>        Required by:
>            project :